# Where is WIF Security Token timeout coming from?

Tags: wif, adfs2.0, adfs, ws-federation

One of the events on the `SessionAuthenticationModule` class is `SessionSecurityTokenReceived`.  This allows us to look at the session token that we receive from AD FS.  The `SessionToken` as two properties called `ValidFrom` and `ValidTo`.  In the configuration we have right now, taking the difference between these two is 1 hour.  I have looked through settings in AD FS, but I have been unable to find out how to change this value.  Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comes from the SAML assertion validity time. If you are using ADFS you can change that value using PowerShell. It's not available through the UI

```
Add-PSSNapin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell
Set-RelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "your relying party name" -TokenLifetime 600
```

TokenLifetime is in minutes

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. I do, however, have a follow up question.  In the UI, there is a setting called "Web SSO lifetime".  What does that value control?

Comment: That value defines the lifetime of the cookie for single sign on. Let's say you have two apps trusting that ADFS. If Web SSO Lifetime == 30 minutes and RP TokenLifetime == 10 minutes, your session will expire in 10 minutes but when you get redirected to ADFS to re-authenticate you won't get prompted to enter your credentials because of that cookie (unless you do signout on ADFS).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Do you have any idea why we were getting a value of 1 hour before?

Comment: It's the default TokenLifetime for relying parties. Try creating a new Relying Party and execute Get-RelyingPartyTrust and you should see 60 for TokenLifetime

Comment: It seems like the default for us is 0.